# Call Ajax script from html inside php echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I do have an simple form where i submit a file to an php script.
Inside this form, i have a call to an ajax script in order to prevent the page from refreshing and displaying the results in a .

However, what i'm trying to achieve now is to call another ajax script from within php (within the 'echo' tag(where my HTML is) so i can submit another php script without refreshing the page and hide a few stuff on the page.

I'm trying to figure out, but i can't get it done.

Here's my ajax script now:

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#uploadFile', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "../../sisbltg/function/atualizaPlanilha.php",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#uploadedData').html(data);
      var a = data;
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "../../sisbltg/function/executaSqlOutage.php.php",
        data: 'page=' + a,
        success: function(data) {
          $('#uploadedData').hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I've tried to call inside ajax 'success' and a few other functions (commented) trying to hide the div or the button specifically. None of them worked.
I'm trying to call from something like:

echo 'Do you want to update you files? ';

Here's the initial form from where i call the ajax script: #1

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css-outage.css">
 
 
  <title>Atualizacao </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Rodape" class="Zadra" width="100%">
    Envio de planilhas de outage
  </div>
  <p>Selecione o arquivo a ser enviado:</p><br>
  <div class="envioDados">
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadFile">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviaBtn" class="btnEnviar">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20971520" class="btnEnviar" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="uploadedData"></div>
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: This is where i'm trying to make the 2nd ajax call from. This is part of the file atualizaPlanilha.php (i haven't posted it entirely because its not needed). On the initial form (with #1), is where i make the first ajax call. From there the file is submitted and the processing results are shown in a div. What i'm trying to achieve is to have a 2nd ajax call inside this echo block, where i can call a php function without refreshing the page, and hide the form just showing an 'Updated' message.

```
echo '</table>';
 echo '<br><br><p align="center">Exibindo os 10 primeiros registros da tabela. Deseja prosseguir com a atualização dos dados?<br><center><div id="atualizouDados"><form method="post">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Atualizar" id="atualizar"
><input type="button" value="Cancelar" name="cancelar" class="button2">
</form>
</div>
   </p></body></html>';
```

Comment: You can't call an AJAX script from within PHP. PHP runs on the server, AJAX runs in your browser. What you can do is make the PHP script return some value to the browser, so that in your first AJAX call's "success" function you can read that value, and use it to decide whether to send another AJAX request or not. Then you have have some more JS code in there which may send that second request.

Comment: It actually looks like you may have tried to do that already. So in that case, what exactly is the problem when you run your code right now?

Comment: P.S. We cannot see what atualizaPlanilha.php does, or what it might return. It would probably make things clearer for us if you showed that, and if you removed the irrelevant commented-out bits from your JS script. You can [edit] the question. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue, for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Hello ADyson, thank you fo your reply.  This file (atualizaPlanilha.php) is just a huge php file where i process the data coming from the file, nothing else. But in your first comment i believe you replied my question: I need my php script to return something so i can capture it with ajax from proceed from there. Is that it?

Comment: The problem when i run the code is that nothing happens after clicking the button. I am not able to hide any div or processing a new php script without refreshing the page. But i got what you meant and i'll try to return something and see the results.

Comment: "nothing happens"...are you sure? Have you debugged the code using you browser's Developer Tools (primarily the Console and Network tools) to see what happens to the AJAX request, whether there are any JS errors, what the request returns, etc?

Comment: Yeah i did. The only call being executed is to atualizaPlanilha.php . Nothing else shows on the console (even adding a console.log) or in the network tab (seeing wich files are being received by the browser). Perhaps the flaw is that i'm attempting to do this 2nd call inside an php echo block . Like you mentioned, i can't call ajax from within php, I'll have to figure out a solution.

Comment: `i'm attempting to do this 2nd call inside an php echo block`...are you? In the code you've shown, the second call occurs within the "success" block of the first AJAX call

Comment: I mean this bit here: `$('#uploadedData').html(data);  
                  var a = data;
                  $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "../../sisbltg/function/executaSqlOutage.php.php",....`

Comment: I've edited the question and added more information. ADyson this 2nd call you mentioned isn't working, its what i've tried. While inspecting the page with developer tools, i can't get anything on the console (tried to add a few console.log), and on the network tab it never calls this file (executaSqlOutage.php). All that happens is a page refresh.

Comment: @PabloCosta Just CURL from the PHP if you want the second call's data in the return of the first call

Comment: `All that happens is a page refresh`...it sounds like possibly your jQuery code is not running at all, then. I doubt it's even doing the first AJAX call. (In the Network tool you can see whether something is an AJAX call or not because AJAX calls are marked as "xhr" in the "type" column). After you have submitted the form, can you see an XHR call to `atualizaPlanilha.php` appear in the Network tool, or not?